# Excel VBA - Print range specified in a cell to Pdf and send by outlook

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, vba, printing

I´m very inexperient with Excel VBA but i´m trying do create a Macro that prints to PDF a range of specified cells and send it´s by outlook.

I´m not getting to work the following:

- It´s not saving to the specified folder in cell N9 of my document
- It´s not saving PDF with the name i specified in cell N10
- Most important, it´s not printing the PDF in the specified range i have in cell N4
- Also, is there a way to bypass the part to specifiy the folder where to save the PDF. Just go direct to the email

Here´s the[example file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cIhmt1uxALMxadvjPMpm5UlNG1qSet1f/view?usp=sharing)

Here´s the code i have so far, i´m not experienced in VBA

```
Sub Saveaspdfandsend()
Dim xSht As Worksheet
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xYesorNo As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim xUsedRng As Range

Set xSht = ActiveSheet
Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

If xFileDlg.Show = True Then
   xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
Else
   MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"
   Exit Sub
End If
xFolder = ActiveSheet.Range("n9")
xFolder = xFolder + "\" + xSht.Name + ".pdf"

'Check if file already exist
If Len(Dir(xFolder)) > 0 Then
    xYesorNo = MsgBox(xFolder & " already exists." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to overwrite it?", _
                      vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
    On Error Resume Next
    If xYesorNo = vbYes Then
        Kill xFolder
    Else
        MsgBox "if you don't overwrite the existing PDF, I can't continue." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Exiting Macro"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unable to delete existing file.  Please make sure the file is not open or write protected." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Unable to Delete File"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
    'Save as PDF file
    xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=xFolder, Quality:=xlQualityStandard

    'Create Outlook email
    Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
    With xEmailObj
        .Display
        .To = ActiveSheet.Range("n5")
        .CC = ActiveSheet.Range("n6")
        .Subject = ActiveSheet.Range("n7")
        .HTMLBody = "<font face=" & Chr(34) & "Calibri" & Chr(34) & " size=" & Chr(34) & 4 & Chr(34) & ">" & "Good day dear Master," & "<br> <br>" & ActiveSheet.Range("n8") & "<br> <br>" & Signature & "</font>"
        .Attachments.Add xFolder
        If DisplayEmail = False Then
            '.Send
        End If
    End With
Else
  MsgBox "The active worksheet cannot be blank"
  Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> " *I´m very inexperient with Excel VBA* " 
>   *Someone is being modest.*

I do not see anything that I can point to and say, "this is the problem"; but your code is constantly referring to the `ActiveSheet` and that can be a very dangerous thing.

The problem with hammering the `ActiveSheet` like that, is that you can't be certain the `ActiveSheet` is what you expect it to be. I counted 6 calls for it, that's 6 opportunities for any number of things to change the active sheet and derail your program.

Odd things happen when you start working with the wrong worksheet.  Things like not being able to save a file because it read the wrong cell.  Or it doesn't print properly because the program is reading the `UsedRange` of the wrong sheet.

Now, I'm not saying this is what is causing the problem, but your code is written well enough that I can rule out a problems, and I cannot rule this one.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did not wrote the code from beggining, i just change a few things but im stuck in defining the range to print and choosing the worksheet to print (kinda what you´re saying).